Trouble with Mac Lane's description of monoids
I am referencing Mac Lane's Category Theory for Working Mathematicians, which describes a monoid as a category with one object" (pg. 11) and is the same description given on Wikipedia. I'm having difficulty reconciling that with the idea that a monoid ($C$) can have multiple arrows, with the thought that each arrow should have only the single object $a \in C$ as its domain and codomain. As far as I can tell this is the precise definition which Mac Lane gives for the identity function.
Additionally, in his later chapter on monoids, Mac Lane seems to describe monoidal categories as having multiple objects. For instance, the pentagonal diagram for a monoidal category, $B$ (shown on Wikipedia) lists multiple objects $a, b, c, d \in B$ (pg. 158).
If Monoids have one object, should I be thinking of arrows as having elements of that object in their co/domain? Again from Mac Lane:

A monoid M (in the usual sense, in Set), regarded as a discrete category, is a strict monoidal one with $\square$ the multiplication of elements of $M$.

That makes more sense to me with the usual definition of a monoid, but contradicts my understanding of an arrow, where the cod and dom functions defining a category map to objects in $B$, not the elements of the objects of $B$. I'm also still looking for clarification of why we speak of monoids as having one object, and then referring to the various objects in a monoid.

There are two different ways you can view a monoid as a category: if you take the elements of the monoid as objects of a category then a monoid is a discrete monoidal category; if you take the elements of the monoid as the arrows of a category (with the monoid operations given by the composition and identities) then the most natural choice is to make all the arrows go from a single object to itself.

Please don't use comments to give answers. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work

When viewing a monoid $M$ as a one-object category, all the elements of $M$ are made arrows with the unique object as both domain and codomain. There is no relevant notion of element of the domain or codomain here, because the morphisms in this category are not functions. They are just the elements of the monoid, associated arbitrarily with the one given object. As was commented, viewing a monoid as a discrete monoidal category is a distinct approach, also sometimes interesting.

Thanks for the answer all the way from Topos. The only thing I can't figure out from this is how the identity function is defined. Mac Lane says that given objects $O$ and arrows $A$ in $\mathcal{C}$, $O \xrightarrow{id} A$ is such that dom(id$c$) = $c$ = cod(id$c$) for $c \in O$. If the only object in $\mathcal{C}$ is $c$ though, then all arrows $a \in A$ should be mapped by the dom and cod functions to $c$. This of course violates the idea that id$(c)$ maps to a single arrow in $A$.

No it doesn't. The identity in the single-object category corresponding to a monoid is the monoid's identity element.

@NaïmFavier I'm not sure I'm understanding--is it right to say that the identity arrow corresponds to the monoid's identity element? I'm still not seeing how there aren't multiple arrows in $\mathcal{C}$ that meet the definition of an identity given a single object in $\mathcal{C}$.

Then you need to review the definition of a category again.

@Fifteen12 Every arrow in a monoid viewed as a category is an arrow $m:*\to *$ with domain and codomain the only object, but that's only part of the definition of an identity arrow. The main part is that an identity arrow does nothing to arrows you compose it with.
